# Отвалилась часть локализации футера

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Обведено красным на скриншоте:

> [image: Отсутствие перевода в футере]

Comment: О ... новые ботинки приехали :) Но Николай-то в отпуске!

Comment: `Stack Overflow на Русском компани` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово. По-крайней мере по красным кругам. Справились с помощью американских коллег :) Но, видимо, ещё придется кое-что улучшить.